# Suggestions on how to generate a total from the checkbox data saved in variables

Tags: javascript

I'm designing a PDF Rental agreement that I can send out electronically to customers looking to rent equipment. I currently have two calendar dates they can choose from which displays a total day's used box below. 
That code works like this and is flawless:

```
// get the end date value
var cEnd = this.getField("Drop off Date").value
// get the start date value
var cStart = this.getField("pick up date_af_date").value;
// clear  displayed result
event.value = "";
// compute number of days only if there are values for both dates
if(cEnd != "" & cStart != '') {
// convert date strings to objects
var oEnd = util.scand("m/d/yyyy H:MM:SS", cEnd + " 0:00:00");
var oStart =util.scand("m/d/yyyy H:MM:SS", cStart + " 0:00:00");
// convert into days since epoch date
var nEnd = Math.floor(Number(oEnd) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var nStart = Math.floor(Number(oStart) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
// compute difference
event.value = nEnd - nStart;
} // end calculation
```

Now I have checkboxes that take a daily rental amount (0,20,30,40) multiply it by the day and put the result into a textbox that shows the persons rental fee.
The code looks like this:

```
var cb1 = this.getField("Check Box1").isBoxChecked("0");
var cb2 = this.getField("Check Box3").isBoxChecked("0");
var cb3 = this.getField("Check Box4").isBoxChecked("0");
var cb4 = this.getField("Check Box5").isBoxChecked("0");
var cb5 = this.getField("Check Box6").isBoxChecked("0");
var cb6 = this.getField("Check Box7").isBoxChecked("0");
var cb7 = this.getField("Check Box8").isBoxChecked("0");
if (cb1 && cb2 && cb3 && cb4 && cb5 && cb6 && cb7) {
event.value = "off";
}

else if (cb1){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
else if (cb2){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*30;
}
else if (cb3){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*20;
}
else if (cb4){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
else if (cb5){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*40;
}
else if (cb6){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
else if (c7){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
```

My issue is I want it to add the checkbox totals if more than one checkbox is selected. For example, if cb2 and cb3 are both being used for 5 days, it would be 30*5 plus 20*5 and display the total in the text box. It displays each individual equation in the text box now, just lacking the adding. I have little to no experience and was able to copy and configure these codes to work but have been stuck on this next function for a while. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you just after the numeric total or did you need the full equation displayed?

Comment: Im trying to figure out the equation so it displays a total rental amount for the customer. So a code that adds all check boxes that are checked.

Comment: You already have the data of which boxes are checked correct?

Comment: Correct, if i check cb5 and its rented for 5 days a total of $200 is put into the textbox for the rental fee. Just want it to add incase cb5 and cb3 are checked at the same time

Comment: Sounds like you need a function. Let me see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I've answered however I'm a little confused as to why you have the cb1 && ... cb7 statement setting the value to a string. What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your if cb1...cb7 set the value to 0

```
event.value = 0
```

Then in each of your else if statements change

```
event.value = this.getField...
```

to

```
event.value += this.getField...
```

Comment: Maybe some sort of null check?